# Correctly marking up multiple nested lists within the same list item

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

In a GitHub `.md` file, I'm trying to write the equivalent of:

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is a list item</li>
  
  <li>This is also a list item
  
    <ul>
      <li>...containing a sublist</li>
      <li>with two items.</li>
    </ul>
    
    and then...
    
    <ul>
      <li>another sublist</li>
      <li>which also has two items</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>This is a third list item</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried numerous variations on:

```
 - This is a list item
 - This is also a list item
   - ...containing a sublist
   - with two items.
 
   and then...
 
   - another sublist
   - which also has two items
  - This is a third list item
```

but I've not yet found how to successfully nest multiple separate unordered lists within a single unordered list item.

How should I mark up the line `and then...` so that it (and every line after) renders correctly in GitHub-flavored markdown?

Comment: In general, use Markdown's escape hatch: just write the HTML you want. But what you've already posted seems to work in e.g. https://gist.github.com/, so it's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, @jonrsharpe. Your suggestion sounded like a perfect loophole, so I gave it a spin. Unfortunately, GitHub Markdown's HTML parser doesn't recognise Markdown backticks (it assumes they are literal backticks) and (somehow) the indentation has been lost too.

Comment: What backticks? Once you start HTML, you have to continue HTML - you can't switch back and forth, so you'd use e.g. `<code>` for `inline code`. And again, _what you've posted works_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Ah. I didn't try `<code>` because I thought I'd need to manually add a `style` attribute and look up `background-color` and `font-family` etc. (and this already seemed like the wrong way to go) - but in the event I didn't: I see that `<code>` is a direct drop-in replacement for a backtick. Not sure what's up with the indentation in the markdown (it's definitely not working but the error must lie outside the snippet if it's working for you in a gist). The indentation in the HTML markup is behaving as intended anyway. Thanks very much for pointing me towards the *escape hatch*!

Comment: Rounin you seem to have misunderstood @jonrsharpe. The **Markdown** you posted works. There is no need to use raw HTML or any other hacks. That is unless we are misunderstanding your problem. Perhaps if you could post the rendered HTML and explain what is wrong about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use fake bullet lists to achieve this. You can build them up using non-breaking spaces and a ⦁ (Z NOTATION SPOT) character.

```
 - This is a list item
 - This is also a list item&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;⦁&nbsp;&nbsp;...containing a sublist&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;⦁&nbsp;&nbsp;with two items.
 
   and then...
 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;⦁&nbsp;&nbsp;another sublist&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;⦁&nbsp;&nbsp;which also has two items
 - This is a third list item
```

## Result:

- This is a list item
- This is also a list item
  ⦁  ...containing a sublist
  ⦁  with two items.

  and then...

  ⦁  another sublist
  ⦁  which also has two items
- This is a third list item